# Reassigning keys for just one application or game? (Windows)

Tags: windows, keyboard

Some games have creepy keybinds but don't offer the ability to change them.

Is it possible to temporarily change or copy a key for a game?
For example instead of "up" arrow key, additional "w" key?
Or instead of "i(jkl)", can you use the "w(asd)" key?

It should be so that when I leave the game (Close or switch application), the key assignments in the operating system work again.

It would be super cool if I could even use a gamepad, but I think that's beyond the topic?!

Comment: [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) -

Answer (score 1):

Nice Thanks @DavidPostill .
I didn't know AutoHotkey worked so conveniently.

For the keyboard, this will work without any problems.

For the Xbox One Controller Wireless, I had to tinker something.
It's possible that if you mess around with it too much, Windows will bitch around.
But it worked great for gaming. I tried this in a boxing game.

### AutoHotkey (free software)

For those who want to test it with AutoHotkey...
Keyboard overwriting is very simple just add "w::Up".
For a [JoyStick](https://ahkde.github.io/docs/KeyList.htm#Joystick) you can use "Joy1::Up".

*Note: Xbox One controller works with Joy1 in the Open-Window (Right click on icon, then klick on Open). But not in elsewere.*

But as I said, didn't work with the Xbox One controller.
For this I found one of many "XInput.ahk" files somewhere on the internet.
And built a "Joystick-Test.ahk" with several snippets.
That should be enough to at least get the controller working.

With F1-Key you can activate/deactivate Gamepad Loop.
And with F9-Key you can toggle some debug tooltips.
See Script [XInput.ahk & Joystick-Test.ahk](https://gist.github.com/Cyb10101/88ecdefc683e9fe23ecc00ed03263ec0)

- [Website](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
- [Github](https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L)
- [Documentation v1](https://ahkde.github.io/docs/AutoHotkey.htm)

### ATNSOFT (paid software)

Something I also found was this: https://atnsoft.com/downloads/

I haven't tested this too far though.
But "Key Manager" or "Key Remapper" should work.